# UWP crash after app start: "The internal MapControl framework failed to initialize"

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-mobile

In my Windows 10 UWP app I am using a MapControl and ApplicationInsights. I see reports of crashes of that app, which I cannot reproduce or know how to fix. The only information the crash reports are offering is the following:

> A privilege that the service requires to function properly does not
>   exist in the service account configuration. You may use the Services
>   Microsoft Management Console (MMC) snap-in (services.msc) and the
>   Local Security Settings MMC snap-in (secpol.msc) to view the service
>   configuration and the account configuration. The internal MapControl
>   framework failed to initialize.

Seems like the crash occurs at the app start, as I appears even before the "MainPageView"-eventreport of Application Insights. Is anyone in the same situation or knows a fix for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same issue with a Lumia 925 updated to Windows 10 Mobile, and in the end it seemed that the entire Maps framework was corrupt on that specific device.

You can check that the problem happens to any application that uses a MapControl by opening the native `Maps` application - if it crashes too, you will have to wipe and reinstall Windows 10 Mobile on that device.